# PayPal SecurityException: Requires READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-permissions, paypal

I have some errors when trying to checkout in Paypal-sandbox, errors only occurs in devices with version Marshmallow, other version below than that were work fine.

**Error message**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10179 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)   
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
       at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:4207)
       at com.paypal.android.c.k.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.paypal.android.c.f.B(Unknown Source)
       at com.paypal.android.c.f.d(Unknown Source)
       at com.paypal.android.c.f$3.run(Unknown Source) 
       Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25935(1829KB) AllocSpace objects, 47(6MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 87MB/95MB, paused 7.704ms total 70.036ms
       NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=2177754483, 192.168.0.1, [AC220B8E9BEB], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_REACHABLE}
       START u0 {cmp=com.luulla.mobile.android/com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity (has extras)} from uid 10179 on display 0
       Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@724f030 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@760242f
```

May I know anyone hit this issues ? Is it caused by Paypal-SDK ? Many thanks for the given suggestion and answer :)

Comment: have you tried checking permission programmatically?

Comment: is exception occurring on marshmellow device?

Comment: @apk yes, please read question

Comment: check in Manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: @safinchacko for device with lower then API 23 working fine, i think this should not be the problem

Comment: he is trying to get device id and which need permission to be granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running app in android version Marshmallow, it requires permission from user,  there are 2 ways in solving this.
Either you change your **android:targetSdkVersion="22"** below than 23(Marshmallow) in manifest file.

Or write a function to get permission:

```
// ID to identify phone permissions request 
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_PERMISSIONS = 1; 

// called this when "Checkout" button clicked
// function to get permission from user  
public void getUserPermission()
{
     // check whether "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission is granted or not
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
     {
         // we do not have the permissions, we need to request permission from user
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_PERMISSIONS);
         return;
     }
}
```

When your app requests permissions, system will shows a dialog box to user, you might want to handle the permissions request response.

```
// Write a callback method
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_PERMISSIONS:
            // if request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty
            if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            {
                 // permissions denied. Show message to user with explanations
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setMessage("This app is designed for android version Marshmallow and above. Denying permission will cause unable to Checkout.");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                alert.show();
            }

            // if we get permissions from user, proceed to checkout in Paypal
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // continue with proceed to checkout 
            }
            return;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take permissions at run time if you didn't.
Starting from marshmallow defining permissions in manifest isn't enough.
see this link : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: thanks for your ideas. And I wonder to know is it has any other way instead of get permissions from user ? Like using a updated MPL or Paypal-SDK ?

Comment: That depends on library , if library requires some specific permissions to work. we need to compulsory ask permission to user.
In case of paypal which require `INTERNET` and `READ_PHONE_STATE` both. so you don't have any option with paypal.

But if you downgrade your target sdk from 23 to any lower API. you will get device id without that permission. it will work if declare it in manifest only. but you will not be able to ask for other permissions programmatically. if you want to do so. you have to ask user to do it manually from settings

Answer (score 1):

there is a new released of Paypal MPL that enable to checkout in Paypal without requesting READ_PHONE_STATE permission. Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/88).

Answer (score 0):

```
Call this class where you want to access the phone state.

public class RequestUserPermission {

private Activity activity;
// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
};

public RequestUserPermission(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public  void verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
        );
    }
}
}
```